# Не заливаются ячейки на листе Excel с помощью openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Мне нужно заполнить объединенную ячейку цветом, используя openpyxl

Я использую следующий код непосредственно из документации модуля:

```
with excel_context() as wb:
new_ws = wb.create_sheet("sheet_name")
new_ws.merge_cells('B1:D1')
merge_cell= new_ws['B1']
merge_cell.value = 'Some Value'
merge_cell.fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="DDDDDD")
```

В менеджере контекста файл сохраняется и закрывается. При просмотре листа ячейка остается без заливки цветом. Я пытался просто выполнить целые блоки кода с формированием нового файла excel с залитыми ячейками, но они все равно остаются без цвета. В чем именно может быть проблема?

Comment: fgColor это цвета текста, судя по названию. Фон должен быть bgColor

Answer (score 0):

Такой код у меня сработал, объединил ячейки, вывел значение и залился цветом.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill


wb = Workbook()

new_ws = wb.create_sheet("sheet_name")
new_ws.merge_cells('B1:D1')
merge_cell = new_ws['B1']
merge_cell.value = 'Some Value'
merge_cell.fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="FF3918")
wb.save("merge.xlsx")
```